# image with caption - vuepress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuepress

I'm trying to create a component in vuepress to display an image with its caption. When I hardcode the image path, the image appears but this way I will not have a reusable component. I already try with props, but it doesn't work either.

Here is how I already tried:

```
<template>
    <figure>
      <!-- <img src="../../guides/contribute/images/typora-tela1.png" alt=""/> -->
      <img :src="imagesrc" alt=""/>
      <figcaption>Legenda: {{ caption }} - {{ src }}</figcaption>
    </figure>
</template>
<script>
...
props: ['src'],
computed: {
    imagesrc () {
      return '../../guides/contribute/images/' + this.src // this.image
    }
  }
...
</script>
```

On my README.md I call the component like this: `<captioned-image src="filename.png" caption="Caption Example" />` but the image doesn't appear.

How can I fix this issue? Is it possible to do this with markdown only?

Comment: Please check a working example in codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzaWvO  i believe it might be an issue with the path that prepend (might not be correct).

Comment: If I pass the full URL in src props my code works, but I need to use the image inside my project (I don't know the full URL for the image). Thanks for your example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In markdown (without a Vue component) you can use html,

```html
<figure>
  <img src='../../guides/contribute/images/typora-tela1.png'>
  <figcaption>Caption Example</figcaption>
</figure>
```

---

To make the `CaptionedImage.vue` component work I think you need to put the images in the `/.vuepress/public/` folder.

The difference (as I understand it) is that within the markdown the image path is handled at ***compile time***, but for the component the image path is resolved at ***runtime***.

Anything placed in `/.vuepress/public/` is available at runtime referenced from the page root.

This works for me:

**project structure**

```
<project root folder>
  docs
    .vuepress
      components
        CaptionedImage.vue
      public
        images
          myImage.jpg
    ReadMe.md
```

**CaptionedImage.vue**

```html
<template>
  <figure>
    <img :src="imagesrc" alt=""/>
    <figcaption>Legenda: {{ caption }} - {{ src }}</figcaption>
  </figure>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['src', 'caption'],
  computed: {
    imagesrc () {
      return './images/' + this.src
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**ReadMe.md**

```html
<CaptionedImage src="myImage.jpg" caption="Caption Example"></CaptionedImage>
```

Comment: Thanks, Richard. But the first solution doesn't work, something with the final path image. The second one works. But I have to change the path to `./images/typora-tela1.png`. Thanks

Comment: Indeed you are correct. I think I was a victim of browser caching.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Richard. Based on what he did, I changed a little. So that

- image shows in the center.
- width can be changed very easily.
- caption show in small size and italic font.

**Cimg.vue**

```
<template>
  <figure align='center'>
    <img :src="imagesrc" :width="width" alt=""/>
    <figcaption><i><small>{{ caption }}</small></i></figcaption>
  </figure>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['src', 'caption', 'width'],
  computed: {
    imagesrc () {
      return  this.src
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**ReadMe.md**

For example:

```html
<Cimg src='/images/ml/GAN/永野芽郁.jpg' width='100%' caption="《半分、青い》 玲爱"/>
```

[Here is the final effect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l104s.jpg)